# Find the sum of the numbers in an input file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the sum of all the numbers in an input file but it is not working. Here is my code so far:

```
import re

fname = raw_input("Enter name of the file: ")

fh = open(fname)
for i in fh:
     y = re.findall('[0-9]+', i)

print y

n=0
for p in y:
      n = n + int(p)

print n
```

Comment: Do you want the total of all the numbers or the total of each line?

Comment: of all the numbers. but my program is going wrong at the first for loop where it stores numbers in y list

Comment: Check my answer and you should see that you don't need that loop. Just use `re.findall('[0-9]+',fh)`.

Comment: What does your file look like?  One number per line with nothing else on the line?  numbers with text?

Comment: Note that it is better practice to close the file after using it (`fh.close()` after your loop), or, even better, use a `with` statement so that the file closing is handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
import re
fname=raw_input("Enter name of the file: ")
with open(fname, 'r') as f: lines = f.readlines()
print map(lambda line: sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', line)]), lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work except you missed two things. 1) When you open your file you must specify that you want to open it in read mode. 2) You must read the file. Here is the correct code:

```
import re

fname=raw_input("Enter name of the file: ")
fh=open(fname, "r")
data = fh.read()

y = re.findall('[0-9]+',data)
n=0

for p in y:
      n = n + int(p)    

print n
```